# Is it always required to have __init__ (constructor) in the Python code ? When does it become indispensable?

Tags: python, constructor, super

Take an example of the code below :

```
class Test:

 # def __init__(self):
 #     print("This is parent class constructor")

 @classmethod
 def __Method1(cls):
  print("This is method 1")

 def Method2(self):
  print('This is ,method 2')

 @staticmethod
 def Method3():
  print("This is method 3")

# obj = Test()
# obj.Method2()

class Test2(Test):
    def Method4(cls):
        print("This is method 1")

    def Method5(self):
        print('This is ,method 2')

    @staticmethod
    def Method6():
        print("This is method 3")

obj = Test2()
obj.Method2()
```

I am able to call parent class methods from the child class using its objects. When do `__init__` and even `super` keyword come into the picture?

Comment: When you need them… If your class doesn't need any specific initialisation steps, then it doesn't. But then it's also questionable whether it's actually a useful class in any way…

Comment: What happened when you removed the `__init__` method? Did the class instance still get created?

Comment: Your class _does_ have an `__init__` implementation, it inherits the default one from `object`. As you've demonstrated (and as is true in general) you don't need to override methods if you don't need different behaviour to the inherited implementation.

Comment: Even on removing __init__ method , I was able to create the class instance.

Comment: Yes, correct. `__init__` ***initialises*** the instance, it isn't required to *create* it. The creation happens in `__new__`, which you rarely need to override. Initialisation means that the instance is "set up" or "prepared" in some way with custom steps.

Answer (score -1):

`__init__` is the python equivalent of a constructor if you come from other object-oriented languages. It is used to initialise initialize instance variables that can be accessed using the `self` keyword. `__init__` is the first method that is run when you initialize a class object.

`super` is used to refer to the parent class. It can be used to access attributes and methods, and definitions belonging to the parent class.

Comment: That's what my query is. Even without using super or defining __init__ method, I am able to call the parent class methods using the child class instance. So, when does it become absolute necessary to use either of the two or both ?

Comment: Say you have `Method2` in your child class that utilizes `Method2` from your parent class. You will need to call the parent class `Method2` using `super.Method2()`. Say you have a class `Square` inheriting from class `Quadrilateral`. `Quadrilateral` is initialised using `__init__` with `self.sides=4`. In `Square` you can accept user input for side length. Now to calculate the given square area, you can use `super.sides*4`.